# How do you change the default cache directory when publishing a service in arcmap?

Tags: caching, arcmap

I am trying to publish a service using arcmap and I need to cache the layers on this service when I publish it.

The default cache directory is in a drop down list for which there are no other available options, and this directory is located on the C drive.

However I need to change this so that the caching takes place on the Z drive instead as I have no available space on the C drive.

Can this be done and if so how can this be done? Changing the display cache directory from the arcmap options did not change the location of the cache when publishing a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be set in ArcGIS Server Manager, before publishing in ArcMap.

Instructions are found on [ArcGIS Server help page](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/about-server-directories.htm):

> By default, the server directories [including cache directories] are installed at `<ArcGIS Server
>   installation directory>/arcgis/server/usr/directories`. You can manage
>   your server directories in Manager by navigating to **Site** > **GIS Server** > **Directories**

So you'd want to add something like:

[image]

Comment: I had managed to get this far, but since I was using a different drive other than the local hard drive I was encountering the following error: 
        Failed to register the server directory 'MIPCache'. Cannot write to   directory path 'Z:'. Please check that the location is valid and that the ArcGIS Server account has permissions to the location.

Please note that I carried out this process using the user account which had originally installed arcmap on my server.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you. The caching takes place _on the server_ rather than on a _local_ hard drive, so if I'm publishing from my desktop, a C cache location would refer to the server's drive rather than mine. So a Z cache location means that the server needs to have a drive mapped as Z.

Comment: Yes that is my point, the server has a drive mapped as Z as well as its local hard drive C. However I get the aforementioned error when I try to change the directory to the Z drive.

Comment: Sounds more like a problem for Server Fault, it's not a programming question. Look into whether the user that ArcGIS Server operates as has access to that mapped drive.

Comment: Yeah I could manually access the drive from that user and I even tried the same process from the user account that had completed the installation of the arcgis spftware

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you :/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time anyway :)